# how to change width of charater in svg

Tags: svg, font-size

I want to change character width while font-size will be same.

```html
<svg encode="hex" type="textWrap" width="800" x="20" y="468">
    <text transform="rotate(0 0 0)" font-size-adjust="0.90">
        <tspan fill="black" font-variant="small-caps" char-width="10" font-family="Oswald Medium" font-size="94px" font-size-adjust=""  text-anchor="start" x="0" y="80" stroke-width="5600">[Lithium ion bat-
        </tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `textLength` property. With `textLength` you may want to use `lengthAdjust` to tell the svg how to manage  the change of the text length: the value of `spacing` will space the glyphs. while `lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs"` will space and change the width of the  glyphs.

I've made some changes to your code. Instead of using a width for the svg element I'm using a viewBox attribute. Now the svg element will take the width of the parent element. Alternatively, if you need a width of 800 units you can add it now.

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg encode="hex" type="textWrap" viewBox="0 0 800 110">
    <text>
        <tspan fill="black" style="font-variant:small-caps" font-family="Oswald Medium" font-size="94px" x="0" y="80" textLength="800" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" >[Lithium ion bat-</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```